# For loop stops for no reason

Tags: c, pointers, memory

So I'm trying to make a program to read a ppm file and store it in memory, I've got everything working up to the colors, this function is giving me problems:

```
typedef struct{
    int red, green, blue;
} COLOR;

COLOR * getNextColor(FILE *fd);

COLOR **getColors(FILE *fd, int width, int height){
    printf("\nentered get colors");
    COLOR **colors = malloc(sizeof(COLOR*)*height);
    printf("\nallocated %d space height",height);

    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < height; i++, colors++){
        *colors = malloc(sizeof(COLOR)*width);
        printf("\nallocated %d space width",width);
        for(j = 0; j < width; j++, *colors++){
            printf("\nlooping through to get the colors for point (%d,%d)", j,i); 
            //*colors = getNextColor(fd);
        }
        *colors -= width;
        printf("\nmoved the pointer for *colors back %d spaces",width);
    }

    colors -= height;
    printf("\nmoved the pointer for colors back %d spaces",height);

    return colors;
}
```

I'm passing in a file pointer that is currently pointing at the first digit of the first color, the width = 400 and height is 530. The output looks like this:

```
allocated 530 space height
allocated 400 space width
looping through to get the colors for point (0,0)
looping through to get the colors for point (1,0)
looping through to get the colors for point (2,0)
...
looping through to get the colors for point (398,0)
looping through to get the colors for point (399,0)
moved the pointer for *colors back 400 spaces
allocated 400 space width
looping through to get the colors for point (0,1)
looping through to get the colors for point (1,1)
...
looping through to get the colors for point (398,1)
looping through to get the colors for point (399,1)
moved the pointer for *colors back 400 spaces
allocated 400 space width
```

and pattern repeats this all the way up to

```
looping through to get the colors for point (399,36)
```

then crashes. Any ideas?

Comment: Long time since I dont do anything in c++, the only thing I see and o dont think its related.. Is that you do *colors -= width; and do it without the * later  colors -= height;

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using a debugger to see exactly where it crashes? Often this is a useful hint.

Comment: When it comes to debuggers and C I'm a bit of a moron, I'm just learning C from learning java and the eclipse debugger for java is far better than anything I've found for C yet, no debugger seems to give me the information I need, just a bunch of addresses. Which is why I've stuck to terminal + print statements, If anyone could recommend one to me that is easy to pick up and good to use then I'm open for suggestions

Comment: Visual studio is the best Ide you can use... You can use a breakpoint when I = 399 and j= 35 and step from there.

Comment: @LuisTellez That's a matter of opinion, but there's occasions where VS will suck big time (for example when you're not using windows).

Comment: Yeah... I'm using both linux and windows, linux on my laptop and windows on my main machine. It would be good if there were something I could use on both, and aren't vastly different from one another ;)

Comment: Just don't write obscure code with pointer-to-pointers and you won't write such hard-to-find bugs. Use a pointer to a real 2D array instead.

Comment: @Lundin, but then if I decide to use different PPM files it might not work, this one allocates the height and the width depending on the height and width of the PPM file, I thought 2D arrays can't be initialize with variables in C? Or am I wrong.

Comment: @James You can, variable-length arrays were introduced to the C language _17 years ago_, previous millennium. For this particular case, simply use a pointer to a variable-length array: `COLOR (*colors)[width] = malloc( sizeof(COLOR[height][width]) );`.

Comment: @Lundin, nice, I'll have to try that out, see if it reduces what I have so far :). I guess It makes it more readable than pointers to pointers.

Comment: @James Most importantly, it makes you allocate a 2D array in adjacent memory, rather than individual segments scattered all over the heap. So it can be used as any other 2D array, for example you can use standard functions memcpy, memset, bsearch, qsort etc on it. And there is just one free() call, instead of some obscure for loop that calls free() repeatedly.

Comment: Okay so I'm really confused as to what  COLOR (*colors)[width] = malloc( sizeof(COLOR[height][width]) ); is actually doing. I get that you are making a pointer to a 2D array, but the syntax doesn't make much sense to me. (*colors)[width] says to me you have a single array of pointers, of width size, and you are allocating a 2 dimensional array of color values of [height][width] size to the last element nope. Makes no sense, any reading you can suggest? Because everything on 2D arrays I'm finding uses constants. Not saying you are wrong, I'm just misinformed.

Comment: @James: `colors` is actually not a "pointer to a 2D array", but a pointer to a 1D array. But as usual in C, the 2nd dimension is used by pointer-arithmetic/indexing. You basically allocate a "1D array of 1D arrays" instead of an "1D array of **pointers to** 1D arrays".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with `*colors++` that does not probably mean what you think it does. This is due to operator precedence, highest precedence has postfix increment/decrement operators and lower precedence has indirection. So `*colors++` actually meanst `*(colors)++` which doesn't make much sense. You probably meant `(*colors)++`

Comment: Well done man, I am a moron, thanks. Works like a charm. I'll mark you correct as soon as I can ^_^