# Variable size two dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I've been trying to store a PPM file in a program to be manipulated, I successful stored everything up to the colors, I've made progress on the colors.

During asking a question on stack overflow ([For loop stops for no reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269845/for-loop-stops-for-no-reason?noredirect=1#comment58253178_35269845)) I was convinced that my method was a bit shoddy, however I don't understand the reasoning for using the follow:

```
COLOR (*colors)[width] = malloc( sizeof(COLOR[height][width]) );
```

can someone break down exactly what this line of code is doing and explain what type it is. So I can store it in a struct and successful return it.

Example: 
previously I used pointers to pointers, where I allocated a height and for each pointer I allocated a width. This means that for each pointer I could create a color, increment it along the width until Im at the end, then reset the pointer and increment the height and loop. After I got the full image I return it to store it in the follow:

```
typedef struct {
    char code[CODE_LENGTH];
    COMMENT *commentPPM;
    int width, height, max;
    COLOR **colorValues;
} PPM;
```

using:

```
ppmFile->colorValues = getColors(fd, ppmFile->width, ppmFile->height);
```

and

```
typedef struct{
    int red, green, blue;
} COLOR;

COLOR * getNextColor(FILE *fd);

COLOR **getColors(FILE *fd, int width, int height){
    printf("\nentered get colors");
    COLOR **colors = malloc(sizeof(COLOR*)*height);
    printf("\nallocated %d space height",height);

    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < height; i++, colors++){
        *colors = malloc(sizeof(COLOR)*width);
        printf("\nallocated %d space width",width);
        for(j = 0; j < width; j++, *(colors++)){
            printf("\nlooping through to get the colors for point (%d,%d)", j,i); 
            //*colors = getNextColor(fd);
        }
        *colors -= width;
        printf("\nmoved the pointer for *colors back %d spaces",width);
    }

    colors -= height;
    printf("\nmoved the pointer for colors back %d spaces",height);

    return colors;
}
```

Comment: I think you are right using the 2D array approach. However, please understand stack overflow is no tutoring service, nor a discussion forum. You got some explanations with your original question already. That should have been suffisient to give some "pointers" what to serach for and how to start some research on your own. There are enough books and online-tutorial to be found.

Comment: Sure, not asking for tutoring, im asking for an explanation to a line of code that just seemed to be pulled out of nowhere, I have searched high and low and everything I'm finding has nothing to do with the code provided, does this code have some sort of special name? is it in fact a 2D array, you said in the other question that its a pointer to an array of arrays, which I googled and found nothing. So I thought I would ask here, where I originally found it.

Comment: To be fair, I think we might need a "canonical duplicate" explaining how to properly allocate 2D arrays dynamically. There are some posts on the topic but they lack detailed explanations.

Comment: @Lundin: Not so sure. IMO this question will become obsolete by just following the C syntax. `cdecl` will be sufficient. And I already explained that in a comment to the original question.

Comment: @Olaf cdecl is a crap site though. It says syntax error for `int (*ptr)[x]` and that's not even post-C99 code.

Comment: @Lundin: I actually thought about the tool. Try `int (*p)[2]`, that at least works with the program. It seems to have problems with VLAs.

Comment: @Lundin, @Olaf - not just with VLAs. It also has problems with anything it considers a keyword in its own language, including `ptr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to understand this, you need to first understand the concepts:

- *Array pointers* (not to be confused with pointer to first element)
- *Variable-length arrays*, also known as VLAs.

---

Given that already you know what the above is, then the most formally proper way to do this is to declare an array pointer to a 2D VLA:

```
COLOR (*colors)[height][width];
```

And when you call malloc, you tell it to allocate enough space for such an array:

```
malloc( sizeof(COLOR[height][width]) )
```

You would then end up with

```
colors = malloc( sizeof(COLOR[height][width]) );
```

However, since `colors` in this example is an array pointer, you would have to de-reference it each time you wish to access the array:

```
(*colors)[i][j] = something;
```

This syntax is not practical and also hard to read.

Therefore, you can use another trick and skip the inner-most dimension when you declare the array pointer. Instead of a pointer to a 2D array, you could skip the inner-most dimension and just declare an array pointer to a 1D array:

```
COLOR (*colors)[width]
```

but use this with the very same malloc call as before. Because now you can take advantage of array pointer arithmetic:

```
colors[i][j] = something;
```

Which essentially means, "in my array-of-arrays, give me array number `i`, item number `j`".

It works for the same reason as `int* x = malloc(sizeof(int[n])); ... x[i] = something;` works, which of course gives you `int` number `i`.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: Btw it doesn't necessarily have to be variable arguments/VLAs, the very same applies if `height` and `width` were compile-time constants. But if they are compile-time constants, it may perhaps not make sense to use `malloc`.

Comment: Just to clarify: Something like "array pointer arithmetic" does not exist. It is normal _pointer arithmetic_, where the offset is multiplies by the size of the object the pointer points to. Here the object just happens to be an array.